# Why can't I find element with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

So I've tried almost every method that I knew of including xpath and nothing. It should be a simple find element and click and that's it, but I can't figure it out.

[image]

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

ff_options = Options()

#profile
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\bravoj\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\7k4o5psw.CCC Deafualt')
ff_driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\\Users\\bravoj\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe')
#fire fox driver
ff_driver.get('about:profiles')
#ff_driver.get('about:preferences#home')

ff_driver.find_element_by_id('profiles-set-as-default').click()
```

There is a duplicate code too 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`'profiles-set-as-default'` is not `id` attribute, it's `data-l10n-id` attribute. You can use `css_selector` to locate it, and get unique element using previous brother element with `data-l10n-args {CCC Deafult}`

```
ff_driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-l10n-args*="CCC Deafult"] ~ [data-l10n-id="profiles-set-as-default"]')
```

Comment: This actually worked. but It kept choosing the second profile instead of the 3rd one I was aiming for, the reason for this is because the first one also has the same code set as the element. so the code will run and find tat first one. Is there any way to have it skip that and find the second one. I have provided a picture

Answer (score 0):

The element with text as **Set as default profile** is a dynamic element so to locate and `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.tab#profiles button[data-l10n-id='profiles-set-as-default']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-l10n-id='profiles-set-as-default' and text()='Set as default profile']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```